# Retrieving the ZF in GCC inline assembly

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86

I need to use some x86 instructions that have no GCC intrinsics, such as BSF and BSR.
With GCC inline assembly, I can write something like the following

```
__INTRIN_INLINE unsigned char bsf64(unsigned long* const index, const uint64_t mask)
{
__asm__("bsf %[mask], %[index]" : [index] "=r" (*index) : [mask] "mr" (mask));
return mask ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Code like `if (bsf64(x, y)) { /* use x */ }` is translated by GCC to something like

```
0x000000010001bf04 <bsf64+0>:   bsf    %rax,%rdx
0x000000010001bf08 <bsf64+4>:   test   %rax,%rax
0x000000010001bf0b <bsf64+7>:   jne    0x10001bf44 <...>
```

However if `mask` is zero, BSF already sets the ZF flag, so the `test` after `bsf` is redundant.

Instead of returning `mask ? 1 : 0`, is it possible to retrieve the ZF flag and returning it, making GCC not generate the `test`?

EDIT: made the `if` example more clear

EDIT: In response to Damon, `__builtin_ffsl` generates even less optimal code. If I use the following code

```
    int b = __builtin_ffsl(mask);
    if (b) {
        *index = b - 1;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

GCC generates this assembly

```
   0x000000000044736d <+1101>:  bsf    %r14,%r14
   0x0000000000447371 <+1105>:  cmove  %r12,%r14
   0x0000000000447375 <+1109>:  add    $0x1,%r14d
   0x0000000000447379 <+1113>:  je     0x4471c0 <...>
   0x000000000044737f <+1119>:  lea    -0x1(%r14),%ecx
```

So the `test` is gone, but redundant conditional move, increment and decrement are generated.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of remarks:

- This is an "anti-optimization". You're trying to do a micro-optimization on something that the compiler already supports.
- Your code does not generate the `bsf` instruction at all with my version of gcc with all optimization switches turned on. Looking at the code, that is not surprising, because you return `mask`, which is the *source* operand, not the destination operand (gcc uses AT&T syntax!). The compiler is intelligent enough to figure this out and drops the assembler code (which doesn't do anything) alltogether.
- There is an intrinsic function `__builtin_ffsl` which does exactly the same as your inline assembly (though, correctly). An intrinsic is no less portable than inline assembler, but easier for the compiler to optimize.
- Using the intrinsic function results in a `bsf cmov` sequence on my compiler (assuming the calling code forces it to actually emit the instruction), which shows that the compiler uses the zero-flag just fine without an additional test instruction.
- Returning a `char` when you want a `bool` is not the best possible hint for the compiler, though it will probably figure it out anyway most of the time. However, telling the compiler to use a bitscan instruction when you are really only interested in "zero or not zero" is certainly sub-optimal. `if(x)` and `if(!x)` work perfectly well for that matter. It would be different if you returned the result as reference, so you could reuse it in another place, but as it is, your code is only a very complicated way of writing `if(x)`.

Comment: First, thanks for the builtin -- I didn't know it. Unfortunately, I can't find a similar builtin for BSR -- clz is undefined on x=0, so I need the test explicitly anyway. So I consider the question still unanswered.

Comment: About your other remarks: I think you tested my function in some dead code, because for me it is correctly generating the bsf (the disass above comes from real code, stepping in with gdb) and the operands are correct (otherwise nothing in my code would work, it depends heavily on this function).

Of course I am not using bsf for "zero or not zero", all my code is of the form "if there is at least one bit tell me the LSB otherwise do something else", which is why I need a jmp right after the bsf.

Comment: For BSR, you want `8*sizeof(type) - __builtin_clz(x)` (or `__builtin_clzl` for `long`). This is kind of contorted because the intrinsic is "the other way around", but the compiler emits a single BSR for that construct (I've used it in the past). Now, don't ask me why this intrinsic is the other way around ... probably because "leading zeroes" is a known idiom or something :-)

Comment: _"Of course I am not using bsf for 'zero or not zero', all my code is of the form 'if there is at least one bit tell me the LSB otherwise do something else'"_ so in other words, you are writing something like `if((x = bsr64(y,z))) { /* use x */ }`. Ok, that will work, but it's different from what the question suggested to me. That kind of thing should indeed work just fine with the intrinsic and CSE enabled, too (does for me, anyway).

Comment: Possibly in a small isolated code snippet (though it does not for me), those things are hard to verify in simple 5-liners. However, I yet have to see an intrinsic that does _not_ outperform inline assembler in real code, even in cases where an intrinsic generates an extra instruction. Intrinsics, apart from working correctly, are much less "black box" to the compiler.

Comment: I am very surprised too, but the assembly I pasted comes from a real function, it is not an isolated code snippet. It may be premature optimization, but I am disappointed that with MSVC (that has the intrinsic `_BitScanForward64` with the same signature of my `bsf64`) I can generate exactly the code I want and with GCC I can't. The word I use `bsf` on is more likely to be zero than nonzero, that's why I want as few instructions between `bsf` and `jne` as possible.

Comment: Another option is of course to test for the operand being zero **before** calling the asm routine. If that is the most common case, it might even be an optimization!